# Should I give a gift to my boss with/after my resignation letter?

Tags: software-industry, management, resignation, united-states

I have had a very good experience with the company I am leaving, and want to soften the blow with a small gift to my immediate supervisor. Is this appropriate, wise, recommended?

I'm based out of the Southeastern USA, and in software development.

Comment: I would wait until after any counter offer is made and they have accepted your departure.

Comment: Very good point.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with showing your appreciation for your time at a company. In this day and age, showing your appreciation for a supervisor you genuinely appreciated can go a long way for you and them. With too many mediocre (to flat out poor) managers, those who are good managers and good to their people should be recognized. Goodwill and recognition never go out of style in the workplace.

Comment: Good answer. I would only add that the gift should be modest, given in a private setting, and _clearly explained_ that you are giving it in appreciation for being such a good manager and making it possible to have a good experience while you have worked there. This way, there won't be any misunderstandings about why the gift was offered. (It doesn't happen often, so some folks might wonder whether there are other motives.)

Answer (score 17):

> I have had a very good experience with the company I am leaving, and
>   want to soften the blow with a small gift to my immediate supervisor.
>   Is this appropriate, wise, recommended?

What a nice thought!

A token gift, given in private with a nice note, to someone who has helped make for a very good work experience is always appropriate.

It may not soften the blow of an important employee's leaving, but will certainly leave a positive lasting impression.

Comment: As always, another great answer.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if it's recommended, but I did at my last job (a gift plus a thank you card).  It was appreciated, and they sent one back in return.

Just follow your heart, if you feel like you need to do something to show gratitude, you shouldn't let some "rules" or "convention" to keep you from doing it.  Besides, I doubt anyone hate receiving gifts. ;)